# Chrome MAX_WRITE_OPERATIONS_PER_HOUR error will not reset

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, synchronization, google-chrome-storage

I accidentally created a loop in my chrome extension that caused MAX_WRITE_OPERATIONS_PER_HOUR to trip in about 5 seconds. After fixing the bug and waiting 3 hours I'm still receiving that error when trying to chrome.storage.sync.set(). Why is chrome still responding that I am exceeding the maximum write operations even when no operations have been initialized for several hours?

Answer (score 1):

While waiting for the throttle to clear I had left my chrome browser open (mac OSX mavericks, chrome 31.0.1650.63). Exiting the browser and restarting fixed this issue.